# Unnecessarily restrictive limits - The Wimbledon tennis scoreboard

Tags: overflow, scoring

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isner%E2%80%93Mahut_match_at_the_2010_Wimbledon_Championships

So the longest ever tennis match broke the scoreboard on court at 47-47 and broke the website at 50-50.

At least with the millennium bug it was about the date being stored in two digits.

What excuse was there here and how common is it for programs to be unprepared for the perfect storm, even to the point of being unnecessarily restricted like this ?

Comment: I don't have any specific knowledge, but I bet when they were coding it they tested for bad data.  Someone said "what are the chances it will ever be more than 50 games?  0%?  Then anytime we get that info, we must have received bad data."

Comment: ...and it was over twice the previous record, so the probability was probably so low that it was deemed an acceptable risk

Comment: 47 (or 48) does seem a really odd limit though, 64 I might have understood.

Comment: I'm impressed they got IBM out to "fix" it so quickly. Now that's service.

Comment: @Martin Smith: I think it was 50 (not 47 or 48, actually). And yeah, it's odd.

Comment: I had the same initial reaction (why would you code an arbitrary limit, instead of just letting it wrap at whatever power of two?) - the only thing I can possibly think of is that somewhere along the line, there's a system without a decrement button, so they made it wrap around in case you went too far (think poorly-designed alarm clock).

Comment: @MrXexxed: IBM is one of those companies that produced (still produces?) mainframes that would call for help if they detected a fault, so at times the first indication of a problem seen in the machine room would be the arrival of the guy with dark blue suit, red tie, and field circus box. *"Hi, you model #### is having trouble and I'm here to fix it..."*

Answer (score 1):

To be prepared for every perfect storm, also unlikely ones, means time.

Usually you have to care about exceptional situations that may occur for some believable reason but I don't think you should really cover every possibility also the one that may occur 1 per 10000 games. Then it depends on what we are talking about..

A Wimbledon scoreboard is not a shuttle launched into the space, it's just something that it is acceptable not to handle very exceptional situations, since it doesn't really create such big problems if one day a match lasts 11 hours and score goes over a specific bound: on a space mission you have to care about also events that may occur 0.001% of the time, on a tennis scoreboard you just don't care..